# Android device Id

Tags: android

How to get Hardware Unique Id of Android Phone even if Factory reset or Os update in device. I want to get Unique id which can not change in future on any event like Factory reset or Os update.

Comment: All You Need Is To Research Before Asking!

Comment: Take a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: I Have already research a lot brother but didn't get proper solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: Have you considered the privacy implications from the user's perspective? How will you let them know they are being tracked in this fashion? Will you have a privacy policy?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be helpful:

```
@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to use wifi mac address or buetooth address of device.... they will not changed after factory reset....

Comment: Thanks,let me try

Comment: If you mention hardware identifiers as a method of tracking users, you really should mention the privacy implications. Users often do not like to be tracked in this way, and at the very least their permission should be sought.